# What is an http request multiplexer?

Tags: http, go, multiplexing, servemux

I've been studying golang and I noticed a lot of people create servers by using the `http.NewServeMux()` function and I don't really understand what it does.

I read this:

> In go ServeMux is an HTTP request multiplexer. It matches the URL of
>   each incoming request against a list of registered patterns and calls
>   the handler for the pattern that most closely matches the URL.

How is that different than just doing something like:

```
http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
http.Handle("/home", home)
http.Handle("/login", login)
```

What is the purpose of using multiplexing?

Comment: When you do that, you're using the multiplexer — namely, `http.DefaultServeMux`.

Comment: ListenAndServe will use http.DefaultServeMux if you pass **nil** as the second parameter

Comment: A request multiplexer is also called a request router.  It routes incoming requests to a handler using some set of rules.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From `net/http` GoDoc and Source.

`ListenAndServe starts an HTTP server with a given address and handler. The handler is usually nil, which means to use DefaultServeMux. Handle and HandleFunc add handlers to DefaultServeMux`

`DefaultServeMux` is just a predefined `http.ServeMux`

```
var DefaultServeMux = &defaultServeMux
var defaultServeMux ServeMux
```

As you can see `http.Handle` calls `DefaultServeMux` internally.

`func Handle(pattern string, handler Handler) { DefaultServeMux.Handle(pattern, handler) }`

The purpose of `http.NewServeMux()` is to have your own instance of `http.ServerMux` for instances like when you require two `http.ListenAndServe` functions listening to different ports with different routes.

Answer (score 7):

the multiplexer in Golang is some things like multiplexer in hardware which multiply some inputs into some outputs

i gave you a simple exampe

```
type CustomMultiplexer struct {
}
```

the given multiplexer have to implement the `ServeHTTP` method to be registered int http to server inputs

```
func (mux CustomMultiplexer) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path == "/" {
        SimpleRequestHandler(w, r)
        return
    }
    http.NotFound(w, r)
    return
}
```

my `SimpleRequestHandler` is a method as follow

```
func SimpleRequestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case http.MethodGet:
        mySimpleGetRequestHandler(w, r)
        break
    default:
        http.Error(w, "method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        break
    }
}
```

now i can use my `CustomMultiplxere` to do multiplexing between incoming requested

```
func main() {
    customServer := CustomServer{}
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9001", &customServer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

the `http.HandleFunc` method works as my given simple multiplexer.